# Excel formatting codes

Tags: excel

I am reading the ECMA-376 specification and I am testing my understanding of the matter using Excel for real. I am basically in need of implementing a few of these codes in a GoLang script.

What's the meaning of this format code `#,##0` and why couldn't it be simply written as `#,##`.

In other words what's the meaning of the trailing zero ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `#,##` would return a number `1234` like `12,34`
2. you could do `#,###` which would do `1,234`
3. The `0` is so `0` always shows.  Usually this is in junction with a decimal: `#,##0.00` so it would show `0.50` when the user enters `.5`.  If decimals are not used there really is no difference between `#,###` and `#,##0`